# Selected value isn't displayed while using ngModel

Tags: forms, angular

I have a simple component that doesn't set values of `select`, instead I write values in HTML

```
<select name="select1" ngModel id="s1" class="form-control">
  <option value="Item 1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="Item 3" selected>Item 3</option>
  <option value="Item 4">Item 4</option>
  <option value="Custom Item 1">Custom Item 1</option>
</select>
```

The selected option has value `Item 3`, but this value isn't displayed when I open my page. Without `ngModel` it's displayed.
It also is displayed when I press an reset button (just an input with `type="reset"`).

I have the same problem with checkboxes, radio buttons and simple text inputs as well, but in this case I use `checked` to display default value of radio buttons and checkboxes, and set `value="default value"` in case of text inputs.

Here is the `ts` file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() show: boolean;
  @Output() hideFiltersEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit(aForm: NgForm){
    console.log(aForm);
  }
  onHideFilters(){
    this.hideFiltersEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

There is some methods in this file, but they have nothing to do with setting or reseting the form controls.

How to display default values of form controls without removing `ngModel`, if it's possible, and why all this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the default value in your component class

```
currentValue = "Item 3";
```

And bind that value to the input using ngModel in your template:

```
<select name="select1" [(ngModel)]="currentValue">
```

When the template opens the starting current value will be shown as the default.

Comment: thanks, it helped with `select`, but how to deal with radios and checkboxes?

Comment: Please research how to use radio buttons with Angular. There is a lot of sample code available.

Comment: okay, I've done some research and found out the solution, that was pretty desperate

Answer (score 0):

In the case of radio buttons I had to use two-way binding with ngModel and the variable that contains the value of the checked button. Each radio buttons has to has such binding.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" [(ngModel)]="opt1" class="form-check-input" value="Option 1"/> Option 1
```

here `opt1` is a string `"Option 2"` and the button is unchecked, but a similar radio button with `value` of `Option 2` will be checked.

In the case of checkboxes I had to do the same, but a variable should has a boolean value, true - checked, false - unchecked.